# Check if NSNumber is between two values

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsnumber

What is the correct if statement to check if a NSNumber is between two values? For example between 33 and 66?

```
if ([myNumber intValue] < 33) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective C is an extension of C, so you can combine two comparisons with `&&`:

```
if ([myNumber intValue] > 33 && [myNumber intValue] < 66) {
```

Or modern style:

```
if (myNumber.intValue > 33 && myNumber.intValue < 66) {
```

Comment: if ([duration intValue] > 1 && [duration intValue] < 5000 ){ Bad receiver type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') ??

Comment: Looks like your duration isn't an NSNumber, no need to call intValue then.